# how to add column in dataframe based on some condition from another column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a python data frame.

```
ID              status

5                  
from 4.3 to 5   yes   
from 6 to 7.2   yes
6.3
6
```

I want to add another column ***col***, as
if ***status*** is missing then corresponding value is ***ID*** else substring(first integer in string) of ***ID***

result should be like this

```
ID              status    col

5                         5
from 4.3 to 5   yes       4.3
from 6 to 7.2   yes       6
6.3                       6.3
6                         6
```

sorry for very bad representation of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `findall`

```
df.ID.str.findall('[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+').str[0]
0      5
1    4.3
2      6
3    6.3
4      6
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method, if you don't prefer regular expressions:

```
df['col'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: x if len(str(x).split()) == 1 else str(x).split()[1])
print(df)

              ID status  col
0              5           5
1  from 4.3 to 5    yes  4.3
2  from 6 to 7.2    yes    6
3            6.3         6.3
4              6           6
```

Comment: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'. How to slove this problem of type??

Comment: @MohdBilal To convert to string use `str()` function. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

you can loop and check over

```
import re

df['col'] = None

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, 'status'] == np.NaN:
         df.loc[i, 'col'] = df.loc[i, 'ID']
    else:
         df.loc[i, 'col'] = re.findall(r'\d+', df.loc[i, 'ID'])[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def fun(x,y):
  return (x.split("from ")[1].split(" to ")[0] if pd.notnull(y) else x)

df["sep"]=df.apply(lambda x: fun(x["ID"],x["status"]),axis=1)
df

    ID             status   sep
0   5              None     5
1   from 4.3 to 5   yes     4.3
2   from 6 to 7.2   yes     6
3   6.3            None     6.3
4   6              None     6
```

Assuming `ID` column is string

Answer (score 0):

this is correct, please check it:

```
else:
     df.loc[i, 'col'] = re.findall(r'\d+', df.loc[i, 'ID'])[0]
```